# "Delete from" deletes everything

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-delete

I have a python function that deletes a row in mysql table using `name` attribute as a condition:

```
def delete(table: str, name: str):
    cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE name = {name}")
    conn.commit()
```

I have one row with a `name` attribute equal to "Name". When I use this function with "Name" it deletes every single row in a table.

I'm guessing that it has to do with passed string being same as attribute. But what would be the solution to that problem except renaming attributes?

Comment: have you try to print out the SQL?

Comment: Aren't you missing quotes around {name}?

Comment: I didn't think table and column names could be bound this way; only WHERE clause values should be injected.  The behavior you observe is what happens if the WHERE clause is not added.  I would make sure that the generated SQL is what you are incorrectly assuming.   This seems dangerous to me - ripe for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @duffymo table name is only used inside the code. What I want to protect from injections is attribute name, because it uses user's input.

Comment: Table and column names should not be bound this way.  Bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for one, I think you are missing quotes around name, as well as a semicolon.

For further reading you should also take a look at `Python parameterized query and Prepared Statement`

I do agree with the comments, that table should not be an injected argument for security reasons!

```
def delete(table: str, name: str):
    query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE name = ?"
    print(query)
    cursor.execute(query, (name,))
    conn.commit()`
```

EDIT FULL WORKING EXAMPLE:

```
import sqlite3            
conn = sqlite3.connect("test")

query_create = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    begin_date text,
    end_date text
);'''
    
conn.execute(query_create)

query_insert = '''insert into projects (id, name, begin_date, end_date) values (1,"name","date","date")'''

conn.execute(query_insert)
query_select = '''select * from projects'''

cur = conn.execute(query_select)
print(cur.fetchall())


def delete(table: str, name: str):
    query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE name = ?"
    print(query)
    conn.execute(query, (name,))

    
delete('projects', 'name')

cur = conn.execute(query_select)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Gives Output:

```
[(1, 'name', 'date', 'date')]
DELETE FROM projects WHERE name = ?
[]
```

Comment: You leave the possibility of a SQL injection more open than it needs to be. Use `query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE name = %s"` and then a parameterized query with `cursor.execute(query, (name,))`. Still `table` should never use untrusted source.

Comment: tried your code

it returns `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Comment: what does the print return?

Comment: `DELETE FROM categories WHERE name = %s`

Comment: can you try now?

Comment: Updated it once again. Should work now (hopefully)

Comment: @FloLie Tried it by making variable `placeholder = '?' * len(name)` and inserting it instead of %s. returns `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

Comment: Sorry for the hustle. Your placeholder method does work. I updated my virtual environment and it started working. Thank you very much!